# remove mixed new line characters and digits

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I have this string list:

```
a = ['6306\nHLIAN\nVARIOUS',
 '10215\nSPINA',
 '10279\nPIPERI-\nΜYTER',
 '38003\nCORN\nSWEET',
 '10234ROKA',
 '10232\nANTH',
 '8682PIPER\nYPAITH',
 '8676\nMAROYL',
 '10211\nΚAROT\nROOT',
 '8685AGG\nYPAU']
```

I want to remove the digits and keep the first piece of words. So, I want result:

```
['HLIAN',
 'SPINA',
 'PIPERI',
 'CORN',
 'ROKA',
 'ANTH',
 'PIPER',
 'MAROYL',
 'ΚAROT',
 'AGG']
```

I tried something like this:

```
from string import digits

def clean_list(data):
    remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)
    no_digs =  [s.translate(remove_digits) for s in data]
    results = []
    for x in no_digs:
        if '\n' in x:
            if x.count('\n') == 2:                
                results.append(x.split('\n')[-2])
            elif x.count('\n') == 1:
                results.append(x.split('\n')[1])
        else:
            results.append(x)
    return results
```

and I am receiving:

```
['HLIAN',
 'SPINA', 
'PIPERI-', 
'CORN',
 'ROKA', 
'ANTH', 
'YPAITH',
 'MAROYL',
 'ΚAROT', 
'YPAU']
```

I can't catch the `'8682PIPER\nYPAITH',` and `'8685AGG\nYPAU'` because they have one `\n` and two words between.

Also, it would be nice if the `'PIPERI-'` would come without the `-` symbol (it can be done in a next step though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `strip()` the strings after you remove the digits and take the first string after splitting by `\n`

```
def clean_list(data):
    remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)
    no_digs = [s.translate(remove_digits).strip() for s in data]
    results = [x.split('\n')[0] for x in no_digs]
    return results
```

You can add `replace('-', '')` to the results of the split to get rid of the `-`.

```
results = [x.split('\n')[0].replace('-', '') for x in no_digs]
```

Answer (score 1):

With single traversal and regex matching:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'^\d+\n?([a-z]+)', flags=re.I)
result = [pat.search(s).group(1) for s in a]
print(result)
```

---

```
['HLIAN', 'SPINA', 'PIPERI', 'CORN', 'ROKA', 'ANTH', 'PIPER', 'MAROYL', 'KAROT', 'AGG']
```

Comment: result gives: NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @George, that's because your `'10211\nΚAROT\nROOT'` entry contains non-string char in its `ΚAROT` substring. Retype it (to `'10211\nKAROT\nROOT'`) and see that it works

Comment: You are right. Thanks! (upv)